# Reading mail from open source Mirthconnect

Tags: email-attachments, mirth

I'm facing an issue with Mirthconnect.
I just have a trouble in this process. I like to read the data from mail, is it possible to acheive this in the open source mirthconnect? of version 3.3.1, if so is it possible to read from direct mail?. Apart from the commerical versions like mirth mails.

Answer (score 3):

I made use of JAVA mail library and inserted it in the custom library folder of mirth connect then used the following code in the connector portion of mirth. It works well.

```
  //Fetchmail from Gmail
  var props = new Packages.java.util.Properties();
  props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
  var session = new Packages.javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props, null);
  var store = session.getStore();
  store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
  var inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  inbox.open(Packages.javax.mail.Folder.READ_ONLY);
  var msgs = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
  var currentMessage = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
  var mp = currentMessage.getContent();
  var bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
  var content = "" + bp.getContent();
  content = content.replace(/''/g, "");
  globalMap.put('gcon', content);
  logger.info("SENT DATE:" + msgs.getSentDate());
  logger.info("SUBJECT:" + msgs.getSubject());
  logger.info("CONTENT:" + content);
  //bp.getContent()  
  var receiveId = UUIDGenerator.getUUID(); 
  logger.info("incomingMailID : "+receiveId);
  //Database Connectivity
  var time= msgs.getSentDate();
  var con = bp.getContent();
  var sub = msgs.getSubject();
 //global variable declaration
  globalMap.put('glcontent',con);
  globalMap.put('glsubject',sub);
  globalMap.put('gltime',time);
  return sub;
```

Then you can set the the polling frequency time intervalin the listener which the mirth channel will poll for that specific time interval.

Comment: Please refer this link below which continues this question with a different requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034377/reading-emails-through-javamail-library-with-mirth-connect/45277458#45277458

Comment: A few adjustments should be made for more recent releases of MC: 1. Use `Resource Directories` and not `custom-lib` 2. Check if MC has the libraries you need already packaged before adding Resource Directories. 3. I think `sourceMap` or `channelMap` would be better than `globalMap`